# C# Thousand Dot in string, but keep the normal decimals

Tags: c#

I am working on a calculator and I want to get a thousand dot in my string.
But when i do it like this:

```
double Answer = 12345;
tbAnswer.Text = Answer.ToString("n");
```

But when i do it like that it will give me 1,2345.00

I just want the thousand dot and if my double has 3 decimals, that it has 3 decimals, and if it has 2 then 2 etc like:

```
double Answer = 12345.1; //1,2345.1
double Answer = 12345.23 //1,2345.23
double Answer = 12345.456 //1,2345.456
```

Is this possible or do i have to stick with the minimum 2 decimals?

Comment: What is your `CurrentCulture`? I don't think any group seperator puts itself after `4` digit in any culture.

Comment: All your `1,2345`'s should they be `12,345`?

Comment: InvariantCulture is mine ;)

Comment: @user3683926 Your code doesn't give `1,2345.00` as an output. It will gives `12,345.00` with `InvariantCulture`.

Comment: Yeah was a little mistake, but i mean that the thousand dot must be shown and still get the decimals that is needed...

Comment: Let's say I do 12 * 1.344567... it will probably get me an answer with 6/7 decimals... but if i do 12 * 1,56 it will give me an answer with 1 or 2 decimals... I only want to add the thousand dot and not care about the decimals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not a standard format code that will do that - you'll have to use a custom format code:

```
Answer.ToString("#,###.######");
```

Note that there's not a format specifier that will provide an *unlimited* number of decimal places.  If you want to support native types up through `decimal` (which can have 29 decmial places) you could use:

```
Answer.ToString("#,###.#############################");
```

But that's ugly, and showing 29 digits of precision is rarely practical.

Comment: It looks like that's the only way to do it... At least thanks for your answer :)